# Factory method doesn't return - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm stuck with this issue. I've learnt that my factory method is suppose to return but I've tried many different positions within the code for the `return` to no avail.

My controller from which I'm calling the service:

```
    $scope.updateChosenSet = function(){
        var chosenMeds = $scope.medications.chosenMedications;
        if(chosenMeds.length){
            var n = ['provigil', 'improvest', 'provenge'];

            // in console, Angular is complaining about the below line (just before the dot)
            medicationByNameFactory.callToAPI().then(
                    function(data){
                        console.log("Works!");  // this never fires in the console!!
                    }
                );
        }
    };
```

and my service:

```
angular.module('hsToolkit.services')
        .factory('medicationByNameFactory', medicationByName);


medicationByName.$inject = ['$http'];
function medicationByName($http){


    // first returning callable properties as suggested here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide
    // tried the conventional way, but it's the same
    return {
        callToAPI: callToAPI
    };


    function callToAPI(){

        // this array will be supplied as an argument from controller when this starts to work
        var fff = ['provigil', 'improvest', 'provenge'];

        angular.forEach(fff, makeCall);

        function makeCall(item){
            return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'path/to/api/?name='+item,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                    .then(
                        function(response){
                            // this DOES output to console!
                            console.log(response.data.drugGroup);

                            // I'm getting error with or w/o this!
                            return response.data.drugGroup;
                        }
                    );
        } // closing: makeCall

    }; // closing: callToAPI

}; // closing: medicationByName
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from `callToAPI` function. returning from forEach iterator function `makeCall` does not return from parent function.

Comment: @PSL Current code doesn't show it - but I've tried returning. Namely I tried to `return callToAPI;` Is that a way?

Comment: You dont get `then` as a magic :/, the function **`callToApI` needs to return a promise**, try `return $q.all(fff.map(makeCall));`

Comment: @PSL Thanks, now I know that I don't know `$q` very well and will dedicate some time to fully understand it. Please move your suggestions to an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is angular version of (limited) Q library. `$q.all` will make sure to resolve _only when_ all of the passed array of promises are resolved. If one of your call fails it will go to catch block. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I'm finally getting no error and I'm getting all the values in my controller. So it works,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not returning anything from the `callToApI` method of your factory, even if you return a promise from `forEach`s iterator function (Which is not of any use though) it it only a return value from that function and it does not return from the outer function. You all you would need to do is to return a promise which settles for all of the underlying promises. So make use of [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) and return `return $q.all(fff.map(_makeCall));` from your service method. q.all will resolve only if all of the underlying promises are resolve, if one of them is rejected entire set will be rejected.

```
medicationByName.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function medicationByName($http){

   return {
        callToAPI: callToAPI
    };


    function callToAPI(){
        var fff = ['provigil', 'improvest', 'provenge'];
        return $q.all(fff.map(_makeCall));
   }; 

    function _makeCall(item){
            return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'path/to/api/?name='+item,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    // this DOES output to console!
                     console.log(response.data.drugGroup);

                     // I'm getting error with or w/o this!
                     return response.data.drugGroup;
                });
        }
   };
```

and in your controller:-

```
medicationByNameFactory.callToAPI().then(function(data){
    console.log("Works!");  // this never fires in the console!!
}).catch(function(){
   //Atleast one of the call failed
});
```